# How to copy a piece of css, html and js from one static template to another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, frontend

I have a folder of static files (html, css and js) and I recognised a piece of code (say, a dinosaur animation) that I want to transport to another folder of static files (a separate project of my own based on a different template).

The main question is what is the correct and efficient way to do this. This is my current process:

1. Manually recognise the minimal

   - **html** chunk where this piece is displayed (***div class="dinosaur_animation" ...***)
   - **css** part where the classes are declared (***.dinosaur_animation { ...***)
   - **js** scripts needed
2. Manually copy these pieces to the html, css and js sources of my new project.
3. Rename the original class and function names (all instances of ***"dinosaur_animation"*** renamed to ***"dinosaur_animation_newproj"***) as is frequently the case that there is conflict with classes and functions using the same name in the new project.

I have successfully transported the pieces from one template to another using this process a couple time, but I am aware that it is extremely inefficient and there should be a smarter way of doing this. For lack of terminology knowledge, I also couldn't google properly.

Could you kindly give a step by step of a smarter way of doing this?

As extra points, can you help me to express what I have just described using correct terminology and antecipate if I can do the same if I am using Wordpress rather than handling static files directly? As everything seems to be wrapped into php and changing original files is regarded as a bad idea, I presume the answer is no...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about **modularity**. This is the term we use in development to describe code and applications that are build in a way that allow us to do this feat you're trying to do.

Modularity is not a concept from this or that language, but a concept about programming in general. So, if you need to read about it, just look for "modularity css", modularity js" or something.

Now, about what you're trying to do, it is easy when the actual component you want to share between projects are already made in a modular way. If it's not, could be a pain to do it. In that case, you should first rewritten the code in a modular way, and then the copy will be just intuitive.

There's no "step-by-step-guide" to achieve this, trust me. Beeing capable of write modular code is not in the realms of "tactics", it is much more a strategy *per si*. You should read about it, implement modular ideias more and more, until you have a grasp of it, and if you're persistent enough, you'll end with code that could easily be shared between different projects, and that's the whole goal, in the end.

For HTML/CSS, I recommend you to read about **BEM (Block Element Modifier) structures**. Seems to me the best way to keep your code modular. In JS, there's a lot of discussion and methodologies that achieve the same result, so just google it out.

P.S.: Wordpress for sure has its own modules, so, if you understand how they work, you certainly can take advantage of this and use it whatever way you want.